# Delphi dbgrid continuous scrolling

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, tdbgrid

I'm making an application that holds orders and prints invoices. I have some labels, tedits, tmemos, buttons, a datasource, an adotable, a popupmenu, and a dbgrid on my form.

When I build the program and scroll down the dbgrid scrollbar, it scrolls after I release mouse button. But i want continuous scrolling.

Greetings

Comment: Isn't that the nature of data aware controls?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's called thumb tracking. Derive a new class to override scrolling behavior. Example of using an interposer class:

```
type
  TDBGrid = class(DBGrids.TDBGrid)
  private
    procedure WmVScroll(var Message: TWMVScroll); message WM_VSCROLL;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    ..

implementation

procedure TDBGrid.WmVScroll(var Message: TWMVScroll);
begin
  if Message.ScrollCode = SB_THUMBTRACK then
    Message.ScrollCode := SB_THUMBPOSITION;
  inherited;
end;
```

You can also replace the [`WindowProc`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TControl_WindowProc.html) of the control if you don't want to derive a new class. All you need to do is to handle [`WM_VSCROLL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397158/delphi-drag-drop-with-listview/5397705#5397705) is an example how to do that.

Comment: Is the non-tracking of `TDBGrid` a design choice to avoid hammering the database whilst scrolling? This is an honest question asked in ignorance by someone who knows absolutely nothing about databases.

Comment: @David - Very likely.. But the option should have been given to the developer anyway. Sometimes all field data is cached anyway, there's no point then to not to have thumb tracking.

Comment: I've got an error "Undeclared identifier DBGrids".. how to fix this? thnx.

Comment: @user - Ask a new question when you have a question.. unless it has been answered before. This has been probably answered many times. Anyway, replace 'DBGrids' with 'Vcl.DBGrids'.

Comment: thnx a lot bro! HAPPY NEW YEAR!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the other solution Sertac Akyuz mentioned without having to derive a new class from TDBGrid:

```
  private
    FOrgDBGridWndProc: TWndMethod;
    procedure DBGridWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
  // ...
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FOrgDBGridWndProc:= DBGrid1.WindowProc;
  DBGrid1.WindowProc := DBGridWndProc;
end;

procedure TForm1.DBGridWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if (Msg.Msg = WM_VSCROLL) and
    (LongRec(Msg.wParam).Lo = SB_THUMBTRACK) then
  begin
      LongRec(Msg.wParam).Lo := SB_THUMBPOSITION;
  end;
  if Assigned(FOrgDBGridWndProc) then
    FOrgDBGridWndProc(Msg);
end;
```