# FireDac Polling records on demand and show them in StringGrid

Tags: delphi, firedac

I am using Delphi 10 Seattle, FireDac, Oracle Database and the TMS Components.

I am looking for a method that allows me to load data from my dataset/query and put it on a `StringGrid` on demand. I think the correct expression would be `paging`.

When i have a huge number of records (5000+) my application is freezing (~5s) till it loads all of them in the grid.

I've read the wiki post from Embarcadero about [Fetching Rows](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Fetching_Rows_%28FireDAC%29) but i didn't find a solution there.

I tried different combinations of the TFDQuery `FetchOptions` and `ResourceOptions` but without luck.

I noticed that the SQLDeveloper by Oracle performs exactly how i want my application to behave.

I've recorded this short clip to demonstrate how the SQLDeveloper loads massive amounds of records:
https://gfycat.com/BlankOrganicIndianpalmsquirrel

It first loads 50 records and as I scroll through the grid the other records get loaded.

So the question is how can i get the same polling technique like SQLDeveloper. 
Thanks!

EDIT: Was using LiveBindings. Switched to db-aware components and it looks fast as lightning now.

Comment: Are you using a db-aware grid or LiveBindings (which seems way slower, ime, particularly if there are more than a few columns).  5k records shouldn't be a problem, speed wise (50k might start to be).  Anyway, it's best to get the data from the server in a background thread, then update the GUI when that's done.

Comment: Use a TDBGrid, which does all of this buffering for you.

Comment: @MartynA I am using LiveBindings and the TMS non-db-aware grid

Comment: @KenWhite I'll have a look at TDBGrid and the db-aware component TMS offers.

Comment: What @KenWhite says.  If you're interested in performance, grid-wise, forget LiveBindings (and TMS )and take a look at the Developer Express TcxGrid.  Their libraries are pricey but are my first choice every time.

Comment: @MartynA Thank you and also Ken. I switched to the DB aware components and it doesn't even take 1s to load everything. TIL: Do not use LiveBindings.

Comment: Glad you got an improvement.  Fwiw, I think LiveBindings is a pretty amazing bit of technology, considering what it can do (incl platform-independence).  But grid displays aren't its strong point.

Comment: As you've solved this yourself, I think you should post your solution as an answer, for the benefit of future readers with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments i gained a huge performance speed by switching from LiveBindings to the DB-aware component DBGrid.

For smooth scrolling i used this SO answer:
[Delphi dbgrid continuous scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918923/delphi-dbgrid-continuous-scrolling)